# GWT: how to regenerate the gwt.rpc file in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, gwt-rpc

We have a large GWT project using GWT 2.3 and eclipse Helios. After running just fine for a long time, I returned to this project and suddenly got various RPC errors, including a message about the gwt.rpc file not loaded. Research here told me to delete it, so I did, along with a bunch of .cache.html files in the same directory. But now when I attempt to start the project in dev mode, nothing works. I assume this is because none of those files I deleted have been re-created. I've gone thru several iterations of cleaning the temp files that GPE creates; restarting eclipse, rebuilding the project, etc. etc.

How do I regenerate these files? The GWT RPC docs say these files are generated during compile. Is this file not regenerated in dev mode?

Comment: Have you tried compiling?

Comment: Deleting `.gwt.rpc` files and `.cache.html` files is ok. Those files are created by the compiler. Like @RileyLark said, run GWT compile using the GWT plugin button on Eclipse, and compile your application's main module.

Comment: thanks for the replies, but I can't compile either because it is wrongly reporting missing CSS selector messages in a ui.xml file; I guess that should be a separate question